# sql: find the suppliers who supply all the parts

Tags: sql

if you have two tables Supplier,Part

How to select suppliers who supply all parts? it can be from parts column in Supplier or suppliers column in Part or any other way

Comment: please describe more, tell us what do you have now and what's your expected result

Comment: A [mcve] would make things clearer!

Comment: I am new to sql, what I came up with is a suppliers column in Part but I don't know how to specify the suppliers that are in every column

Comment: GROUP BY and HAVING can perhaps be useful. Show us what you've got, and we can perhaps direct you to the correct query.

Comment: for example, the Supplier table has (id, name, parts) columns and the Part table table has  (id, name, suppliers). there is no specific answer I just want to know how to find out what supplier supplies all the parts. thanks